# NppExec console output to CMD window

Tags: java, notepad++, nppexec

I have just started using Notepad++ for writing, compiling and running simple java programs.
I found nppexec very quickly, and I'm currently using this script to compile and run:

```
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
javac $(FILE_NAME)
java $(NAME_PART)
```

However I want the java program to actually be ran in a CMD window, not the console window, as I find it easier to use a detachable window.
I have tried this:

> cmd /k start javac $(FILE_NAME)  && java $(NAME_PART) pause

But it does not produce the result I expected. It still shows the output in the console window that is fixed at the bottom of npp.

The desired result I'm looking for is for example when using Scanner in java, I would like to do input in the CMD window, not the console window fixed in npp.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be a good idea to have a read over [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Sadly software specific questions are off topic. You could try the [Notepad++ community forums](http://community.notepad-plus-plus.org)

Comment: Alright, my bad, thanks for referring me!